# Unable to run spring mvc project on local server

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to continue a web application in spring mvc that was done by another person. However, I could not run the project on local server using eclipse and idea intellij. I just imported the project using existing sources. How to run the project on tomcat or glassfish. Help please!!!

Comment: error message or something? adding a tomcat and deploy the webapp in this it's not rocket science.

Comment: Please improve the question by adding code, logs, errors, etc - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: without stacktrace of error is hard to predict...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I wished to write this in the comment section but my low reputation ranking is not allowing me to do so.

I use `Eclipse` and the usual behavior is the embedded server such as `Tomcat` would give a deployment error but when deployed in a standalone server the problem is no longer there or the error message is different.

Please try to deploy your spring-mvc app into an equivalent version of local standalone server and see whether the problem still exists. Also, if there is any logging available, set to appropriate level to see the full log details.